# Ошибка отправки email через SMTP из telnet

Tags: email, smtp, sendmail, mail.ru, telnet

Добрый день.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, по такому вопросу:
Когда я подключаюсь к SMTP сервису через командную строку (telnet), я вижу приветствие сервиса. Но когда я пытаюсь ввести команду, то когда я успеваю ввести 2-4 символа, сервис отвечает:

> ```
> 220 <скрыто> Service ready
> EH500 command unrecognized
> 500 command unrecognized
> L500 command unrecognized
> ```

Похожая ситуация имеет место и когда я пытаюсь подключиться через сокет (C#) — получаю только приветствие сервиса, и на все мои команды сервис отвечает ошибкой 500 (как в цитате выше).

Подскажите, это я неправильно к сервису обращаюсь. или он неправильно работает? Сам SMTP сервис самописный.

Команды, которые я даю сервису:

- EHLO smtp.server
- MAIL FROM:
- RCPT TO:
- DATA
- тект письма
- QUIT

Comment: Было бы неплохо увидеть последовательность команд которую вы вводите, и то, что вы пытаетесь ввести

Comment: Согласен с @Vlad Vlad - дайте больше данных

Comment: Я дополнил вопрос. спасибо